# Python selenium send_keys not working can’t set login fields

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am using selenium to scrape twitter (not using the api's just practicing selenium) which require login when it coms to following page, am using the following code to locate the login input fields and then send the username and password string:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="Chrome")
driver.get("https://twitter.com/login")
username = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='page-container']/div/div[1]/form/fieldset/div[1]/input")
username.send_keys("username")
password = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='page-container']/div/div[1]/form/fieldset/div[2]/input")
password.send_keys("password")
password.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

driver.get("http://twitter.com/user/following")
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

the code is working except for the second field (password field) it didn't send the password strings and skips it to the next line (Keys.ENTER) and next it moves to the following page which require a login, however the cursor was at the password field which mean it already located it, strange enough there is no error message or error code when executing the script.

any thoughts what is the cause of this issue ??

am using python 2.7.6
selenium version 2.53.6
on ubuntu 14.04

thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of sending the ENTER key, just click on the Log in button. Also, your XPath is kinda brittle. I would use a more specific one or you can use the CSS selectors below.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#page-container input.email-input").send_keys(username);
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#page-container input.js-password-field").send_keys(password);
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button.submit").click();
```